# How to (StartsWith) start with 4th letter?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, startswith

I have a question. I want to copy specific files in **'New folder'** to **'Target' folder** by clicking a button. In 'New folder' contains various of file with different name. For example: **"abcUCU0001"**, **"abbUCA0003"**, **"hhhUCU0012"**, **"aaaUCS0012"** and many more. 'New folder' contains more than **1000 files** and have same 10 letters in its name. I want to copy 10 files and its name must have **"UCU"**. I don't know how to copy using **(startsWith)** starting with **4th** letter.
Sorry for my bad grammar.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string FROM_DIR = @"C:\Users\Desktop\Source";
    string TO_DIR = @"C:\Users\Desktop\Target";
    DirectoryInfo diCopyForm = new DirectoryInfo(FROM_DIR);
    DirectoryInfo[] fiDiskfiles = diCopyForm.GetDirectories();
    string filename = "UCU";
    int count = 0;
    foreach (DirectoryInfo newfile in fiDiskfiles)
    {
       try
       {
            if (newfile.Name=="New folder")
            {
                foreach (FileInfo file in newfile.GetFiles())
                {
                    if(file.FullName.StartsWith(filename))
                    {
                        File.Copy(file.FullName, Path.Combine(TO_DIR,file.Name));
                        count++;
                        if (count == 10)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    MessageBox.Show("success");
}
```

I expect after click a button, 10 files with name "UCU" will copied to Target folder.

Comment: you need to copy fine name tat contains UCU?? or containes UCU at position 4??

Comment: Hello Sir, contains UCU at position 4

Comment: `if(file.Name.StartsWith(filename))` - you don't want to check if *FullName*, e.g. `C:\MyFolder\...` starts with `UCU`

Comment: Thank you sir, I have changed FullName to Name and now it is works by using this code if (file.FullName.IndexOf(filename) == 3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the files are in the same directory (no sub-directories), then you can get all files using:

```
    //assuming diCopyForm is the new folder reference
    // ? denotes 1 character while * is multiple chars
    var files = diCopyForm.GetFiles("???UCU*");
```

And then just copy them across. For more complex criteria, I would get all the files and use LINQ to filter through.

[Details about the search pattern used](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.8)

If there are a lot of files in the folder then it might be more efficient to use the [EnumerateFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles?view=netframework-4.8) method

> The EnumerateFiles and GetFiles methods differ as follows: When you
>   use EnumerateFiles, you can start enumerating the collection of names
>   before the whole collection is returned; when you use GetFiles, you
>   must wait for the whole array of names to be returned before you can
>   access the array. Therefore, when you are working with many files and
>   directories, EnumerateFiles can be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if file name has "UCU" in 4th position with [string.IndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.8):

```
//string filename = "UCU";
if (file.FullName.IndexOf(filename) == 3)
```